# detect user being AFK from the browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm writing an internal business application and I have a requirement to track time spent by the user on a particular task. The user is filling a form, but he can access other pages / documents to get required information.
The simple approach is to assume user to be AFK if he did not interact with the page for 5 minutes. But - it will have 5 minute inaccuracy, it will ignore breaks shorter than 5 minutes, etc. And it will completely break if they spend 30 minutes reading some large document.

The better approach would be to somehow detect that the user is not moving his mouse/not using keyboard - at all, not just in this particular browser window.
Is it possible to achieve in a reasonable way? Users have no flash or Java installed (would it be possible with flash?).
I need to support IE8 and Chrome.

Comment: Just bind events to the document/body for the common mouse/keyboard events. If nothing happens in a certain period of time, they could be considered AFK. So that means look into `setTimeout` as well

Answer (score 1):

A easy solution would be to put onclick and onkeydown within the body

Something like

```
<body onclick='this.resetTime();' onkeydown='this.resetTime();'> code </body>
```

Of course if you have other functions which need to do things on the click / keydown you can embed the reset time within them.

this.resetTime() is also just a made up pseudo function, you'll have to make your own.

Comment: This is what I described as the "simple approach". I know I can do this and it is not sufficient for the reasons I mentioned. The question is how to do it better?